# iOS 13 Project without Storyboard displays funny

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

I have this project that is not using storyboards when I run it on my iPhone simulator it is not coming up full screen ?
[image]

Comment: It is always useful describe to problem in detail.

Comment: Basically I have Hand coded my my window.RootViewController and set it up in the AppDelegate window = [UIWindow new]; window.rootViewController = [MyViewController new]; [window makeKeyandVisible]; and the root view shows up like a page sheet

Comment: It looks like UIScreen.mainscreen is reporting a width of 320 and height as 480

Answer (score 1):

From the viewcontroller property inspector select the presentation and set it to full screen it will work check the below image

[image]

Comment: The post owner said that he don't using storyboards

Answer (score 1):

check the content mode it should be scale to fill and size as freeform

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add below image to your project. Using the name **Default-568h@2x.png**

Because Xcode doesn't know your app size so this will pickup smallest size 320x480. With this image and name I suggest above, Xcode will recognize your app support bigger size.

Don't worry when running your app in smaller device, it's still OK.

Image [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6UlH.png)

Comment: Suggestion: It would be great if you create a link with above image and posted here.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to issue in launch screen. I also setup the project without storyboard but deleted the LaunchScreen.Storyboard as well and ended up getting the same screen as yours. After I recreated the project but leave the launchScreen file i was able to get the full screen display for my viewcontroller